# Create (semi-) public invitation link that includes admin approval in Slack

Tags: admin, slack

I am the owner of a slack workspace and would like to create an invitation link that people can click on, but instead of automatically joining the workspace, I want to be able to 'put them on hold' to identify them and to check their e-mail address. Is there any way to do this?